# ESC \ POS Command - Setting User Settings

Tags: c#, epson

First I'd like to say that long time reader of this site! Has saved me a lot from some problems that I've run in to while learning how to develop applications (specifically in c#).

Now on to the problem I am facing. I am currently developing an application that will set the speed and the power supply unit values on the EPSON TM-T88V to the values of 13 and 3 (speed and PSU). I have been using the provided commands located [here on EPSON's Site.](https://www.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=228) I am able to communicate with the printer by sending simple commands such as cut paper and line feed using hex in c# (using RawPrinterHelper), So I know I am able to connect to it. When I attempt to enter the **user setup** by using the values provided in their website, the printer seems to just "lock up". I have to rest the printer after about 2 minutes for me to be able to use it again. Thankfully, it doesn't seem like its writing anything at all to the printer, which is probably why it hasn't failed yet.

Does anyone have any experience changing settings to POS printer (specifically EPSON) who could help me with this? Usually there's a tool that will allow you to just send a .txt file with HEX values (like TPGs), but I cannot seem to find anything like that for EPSON POS printers. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset a printer (ESC @) before start a user settings commands. It helped for me in the same case.